# Plutus-Start for Windows - Cannot get the docker repository to run (A mount config is invalid.)

Tags: plutus, vscode, docker

I am following :
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter

I have downloaded VSCode and Docker. I downloaded the Remote Development extension in VSCode. I then ran "mkdir -p ~/.cabal/packages" in the terminal per the tutorial. All is well.

When I try to clone the repository to container it runs for a good bit and then displays this error:

> A mount config is invalid. Make sure it has the right format and a
> source folder that exists on the machine where the Docker daemon is running.

I can then select "Open devcontainer.json in Recovery Container". Is there some setting I can tweak in this file that fixes the problem? Im on Windows 10, 64-bit, with fresh installs of Docker and VSCode.

My devcontainer.json file looks like this:

{
"name": "Plutus Starter Project",
"image": "docker.io/inputoutput/plutus-starter-devcontainer:v1.0.8",

```
"remoteUser": "plutus",

"mounts": [
    // This shares cabal's remote repository state with the host. We don't mount the whole of '.cabal', because
    // 1. '.cabal/config' contains absolute paths that will only make sense on the host, and
    // 2. '.cabal/store' is not necessarily portable to different version of cabal etc.
    "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.cabal/packages,target=/home/plutus/.cabal/packages,type=bind,consistency=cached",
],

"settings": {
    // Note: don't change from bash so it runs .bashrc
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
},

// IDs of extensions inside container
"extensions": [
    "haskell.haskell"
],
```

}

**Edit:** In the .devcontainer/devcontainer.json file, there is a reference to your source folder for cabal/packages. When I replaced the default path with my specific path, I was able to get it to work.

Comment: can you please show your full line "source=$...." in your devcontainer.json ? I would like to see exactly how you referred to your source folder in this line .. struggling with this .. Thanks a lot & kind regards,
Pieter

Comment: I have the same issue here and can't work out the solution based on the Edit above. Please give an example of a working source folder reference! Thanks!